# How to refresh collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

**My problem is that when I save the picture to photo library my collectionView does not update.** If I click on the first picture it opens the picture I saved recently but visually collectionView never updates. I thought that reloadData() works this way but I guess it's not.

When the app loads user picks the photo from the collectionView (iPhone photo library) then sends it to another view where he edits the picture and then saves it to the library and goes back to the first view using unwind segues.

My code:

```
class pickerViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var activityIndicator:UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()

    var imageArray = [UIImage]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        mygtukasMenu.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        mygtukasMenu.clipsToBounds = true
        grabPhotos()
        kolekcija.reloadData()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var kolekcija: UICollectionView!
    func grabPhotos(){

        let imgManager = PHImageManager.default()

        let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
        requestOptions.isSynchronous = false
        requestOptions.deliveryMode = .opportunistic // Quality of images
        requestOptions.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true

        requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
        requestOptions.progressHandler = {  (progress, error, stop, info) in
            print("progress: \(progress)")
        }

        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]





        if let fetchResult : PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions) {

            if fetchResult.count > 0 {
                for i in 0..<fetchResult.count {

                    imgManager.requestImage(for: fetchResult.object(at: i) , targetSize: CGSize(width: 150, height: 150), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: {
                        image, error in
                        self.imageArray.append(image!)


                    })
                }
            }
            else {
                print("You got no photos")
                kolekcija.reloadData()
            }
        }
        kolekcija.reloadData() // UPDATED
    }


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        grabPhotos()
        kolekcija.reloadData() // UPDATED
    }


}
```

Comment: try calling `grabPhotos()` in `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad` and call reloadData once the fetch completes

Comment: @Scriptable Sadly, it's not working :(

Comment: Show your updated code in an edit to your question. viewDidLoad only loads once in a VC's life cycle

Comment: @Scriptable I wrote the comments // UPDATED in my code.

Comment: hi, u need call reloadData() when u get picture

Comment: Ok your issue is that your not dealing with async tasks properly. fetching assets takes time... calling grabPhotos and reloadData on the next line wont work.

Comment: Please shorten your code and show only what is required for this question. It's really time.consuming to read through tons of lines and try to find what's relevant.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Edited.

Comment: @AleyRobotics Your code is not working for me. I did exactly like you said. Something is wrong..

Comment: what wrong? What debugger message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem is to remove all images from imageArray every time I load the view. I don't know why it's so important but finally it's working. And there's no need to call reloadData() inside requestImage block. (in my case)

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.imageArray.removeAll()
    grabPhotos()
    kolekcija.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

u need call reloadData() when u get picture at func grabPhotos() in block

```
imgManager.requestImage(for: fetchResult.object(at: i) , targetSize: CGSize(width: 150, height: 150), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: {
                    image, error in
                    self.imageArray.append(image!)
                    self.kolekcija.reloadData() <<<<< HERE RELOAD CALL NEED
                })
```

when u call

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    mygtukasMenu.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    mygtukasMenu.clipsToBounds = true
    grabPhotos() <<< photos still grabbing at async mode
    kolekcija.reloadData() <<< there is no images grabbed... it still grabbing at async mode when u call reload func here.....
}
```